# Retrieving story ids from VersionOne

Tags: versionone

I am using commitstream feature to integrate VersionOne with bitbucket. The story id must be given to a particular commit message in Bitbucket. In case of numerous stories, remembering all the story-ids become impossible. So I have decided to create a UI which displays all the story ids of a particular project.

How to retrieve the story-ids in a project from VersionOne? Is there any specific web service for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for info about the rest-1.v1 or query.v1 api.

Short answer:

rest-1.v1/Data/Story?where=Scope="Scope:123456"&sel=ID

Comment: Thank you JoshGosh.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer ? It is difficult for me to understand since I am completely new to this domain.